# Attaching SVN working copy to tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I have a project that I have downloaded from SVN using Eclipse plugin Subclipse.  I now want to stop using subclipse to manage the versioning, and start using TortoiseSVN.  Is there a way to "attach" my working copy so that Tortoise can manage it?  I don't want to re-download the project as it was a huge pain setting everything up in the first place (i.e. that will be the last option).

Note: I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about working copy versions. If your local working copy format version for Subclipse matches the one for TortoiseSVN you can use your checked out local working copy as they are (TortoiseSVN indicates this by showing icons for the files in your explorer). However you should double-check this in the Subclipse and TortoiseSVN home pages respectively.

If your working copy format versions match you can also switch between Subclipse and TortoiseSVN as you see fit.

Now if this doesn't work for you already, there is a mismatch between the working copy formats. With your scenario this is what you need to do:

- Your Subclipse working copy format version is lower than your
  TortoiseSVN version. If that is the case all you need to do is to
  upgrade the working copy format which TortoiseSVN can do for you. If
  I remember correctly TortoiseSVN will suggest to do this
  automatically, but I know for sure that you can use the command 'svn
  upgrade' on a command prompt on your working copy. After running this
  it will no longer work for your Subclipse until you upgrade it to
  match the same working copy format version.
- Your Subclipse working copy format version is higher that your TortoiseSVN version. I suggest you upgrade to a later (the latest?) version of TortoiseSVN.

NOTE! In all this, the important is not which version if Subclipse or TortoiseSVN you are running. The important is which Subversion version it is linked against. On http://tortoisesvn.net/ you can see that "TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 has been released. It is linked against Subversion 1.8.3". In this case the 1.8.3 is the important version and is using the 1.8 working copy format.

Comment: Yep, it was a version difference that was causing the problem.  Thanks!